# Need to remove ruby to install cocoapods

Tags: ruby, rvm, cocoapods

I'm trying to install cocaopods on my Mac Yosemite system. However, when I type in this command:

```
$ sudo gem install cocoapods
```

It returns this error:

```
ERROR:  Error installing cocoapods:
    i18n requires Ruby version >= 1.9.3.
```

Typing `which ruby,` returns:

```
/Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby
```

typing `rvm rubies` gives this message:

```
rvm rubies

       ruby-1.8.7-p334 [ x86_64 ]
    => ruby-1.9.2-p180 [ x86_64 ]
```

However, typing `/usr/bin/ruby --version` gives this message:

```
ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08 revision 45883) [universal.x86_64-darwin14]
```

I'm thinking if I can uninstall the ruby that's in my home directory, the cocoapods install will find the more recent ruby version. However, I'm not not sure exactly how to do that and/or what impact it would have. Any suggestions?

Comment: `sudo which ruby` and `which ruby` will give you two different answers, without very intentional setup especially when using RVM as well.  Remember when you issue a sudo command you are loading a different environment with different rights.  If you need to install a newer version of Ruby for your system (which is the ruby that `sudo` uses) then you will need to upgrade your system Ruby.  I realize this doesn't answer your question, but you are looking at very different things in your question description.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have rvm installed when you don't want to. You can remove it entirely with `rvm implode`. Then when you open a new shell `which -a ruby` should just show `/usr/bin/ruby`

Comment: Thanks, you are correct. I had just found a page which also suggested this and shows how to clean up various ruby and gem versions on a mac: http://cbednarski.com/articles/installing-ruby/